# Animation on delete row from a ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I just started to learn developing for android and I have a question. I don't know if it is possible but well, I'm just gonna ask it. I searched for related topics and I found a lot of them but there aren't topics that helps you to remove/delete a row gradually or smoothly. I mean, I wan to delete it like an animation or something like that. In this code, it just disappear and maybe you don't realize you pressed the button:

```
Button removeButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);
    removeButton.setTag(position);
    removeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
                    elements.remove(index.intValue());
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
    );
```

I don't know if the list layout and the row layout influence the outcome so I add here my 2 XML codes:

**List Layout**

```
    <ListView
         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

    <EditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_above="@id/list"
    />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Row Layout**

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Nom Persona"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edat"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
    android:layout_below="@id/nom"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Edat"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="buttontag"
    android:id="@+id/listbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/eliminar"
    android:text="@string/eliminar"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    />
```

As you can see I added an Editable Text in the bottom, don't pay atention in it.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a premade animation, that you will most likely only hardly be able to customize you can use a library that does that job for you. I think the on delete animation is pretty nice in that library if you can implement the restore thing...
Look up the animation on github and see how its implemented:
[ListViewAnimations Library Github](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations).

Answer (score 0):

visit http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html 
  &&  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html

A default LayoutTransition class will do what you want I believe.